# Replacing failed drive on a ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, vmware-vmdk, datastore

I have a failing drive on my ESXi 4 host and I'm going to replace it. There is no fault tolerance (RAID), each drive on its own.
I'm planning do offline `dd`ing old drive to new one but I'm not sure this will work. Will ESXi properly recognize the cloned new drive or will fail because drive's serial number/model going to changed? What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: The bigger question is if `dd` will even succeed if the drive's failing. You're better off just restoring from backups.

Comment: Well, the correct way to do it is with RAID, on a modern version of ESXi.  [ESX4 went EoL last year](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2039567).

Comment: @NathanC There probably aren't any backups.

Comment: So each disk is it's own datastore? if so can't you just Storage-vMotion the VMs off the failing disk onto good ones, replace the disk, rebuild the datastore and move them back?

Comment: Let's assume that `dd` will success. ESXi 4 general support ended 5 months ago, not last year; it will fully EOL'd at 2016, also ESX != ESXi. I also have backups but they are not at VMDK level. I'm fully aware that is not a "best practice" scenario, I'm just trying to utilize what I have. Thanks for all these comments.